# Making one element for all pages?

Tags: html, element

I am just starting to learn HTML. I am trying to understand if it is possible to only have one element in the mainpage that can be use on every other pages instead of rewriting  it onto every other single html file?

Thank you.

Comment: yes you can! But you need to do this from the server side.  What's your backend? php? python?

Comment: you can do that with some js code.

Comment: Strongly suggest learning either Vue or React if you're still a beginner (although Vue is much easier to use for beginners). That said, I don't advise you to learn Angular right away because it's a full library, so it's a bit more advanced/complicated than the other two.

Answer (score 2):

What you are talking about is called a component. A component is a reusable piece of small elements that you can use anywhere in your html. You can do it in two ways:

1. Server side: Make a function where you store that specific component.
2. Dynamic template: Use something like VueJS,ReactJS or AngulerJS to create and use a component where ever you like it. You can also use JS too. But I suggest VueJS,ReactJS or AngulerJS.